# Parse the request made by browser using python

Tags: python-3.x, html-parsing

```
CONNECT www.google.com:443 HTTP/1.1\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:70.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/70.0\r\nProxy-Connection: keep-alive\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nHost: www.google.com:443\r\n\r\n'
```

I want to parse the request to get url and userAgent and such fields.

Comment: Do you have this request as a string?

Comment: It is in bytes can convert to string

Answer (score 0):

Try something along these lines and see if it works for you:

```
req_str ="CONNECT www.google.com:443 HTTP/1.1\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:70.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/70.0\r\nProxy-Connection: keep-alive\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nHost: www.google.com:443\r\n\r\n"
req_lst = req_str.split('\r')
targets = []
for r in req_lst:
    tmp = r.split('\n')
    for t in tmp:
        if len(t)>0:
            targets.append(t.split('\n'))
targets
```

Output:

```
 [['CONNECT www.google.com:443 HTTP/1.1'],
 ['User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:70.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/70.0'],
 ['Proxy-Connection: keep-alive'],
 ['Connection: keep-alive'],
 ['Host: www.google.com:443']]
```